# On iOS 15 execution of apply(style:) seems to be ignored

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I discovered some problems with my app on devices with iOS 15. I have table view with two sections. Cell is build with UIImageView and UILabel. In class extending CollectionViewNibCell I have overrided property isSelected, so when cell is selected image will have border and label will have its text color changed:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected {
            titleLabel.apply(style: .selectedStyleTitle)
            imageView.apply(style: .selectedStylePreview)
        } else {
            titleLabel.apply(style: .styleTitle)
            imageView.apply(style: .stylePreview)
        }
    }
}
```

For example, selectedStylePreview is declared as follows:

```
static let selectedStylePreview: ImageViewStyle = .init() {
    $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    $0.layer.set(border: .init(color: .orange, width: 2.5))
}
```

On devices with iOS below 15 it is working fine, otherwise it looks like applying style has no effect. I tried to set layer with border directly in collectionView(cellForItemAt) method and border actually appears, but this is not the way I want it.

I run out of ideas, so any feedback would be much appreciated.

Edit: `apply` is used on UILabel and UIImageView basing on https://hackernoon.com/simple-stylesheets-in-swift-6dda57b5b00d

```
import UIKit

public extension UILabel {
    func apply(style: LabelStyle) {
        style.apply(to: self)
    }
}

public final class LabelStyle: Style<UILabel> {}

public class Style<View: UIView> {
     public let style: (View) -> Void

    public init(_ style: @escaping (View) -> Void) {
        self.style = style
    }

    public func apply(to view: View) {
        style(view)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `UILabel` and `.apply(style:)` ... is that a custom func you're using?

Comment: Don't put multi-line code in comments. It's unreadable. You need to edit your original question to include information about any custom/third party code you're using. Include the relevant code as well as a link to the source. (Your readers should not have to wade through the comments in order to understand your question.)

Comment: Good point @DuncanC, I've posted code used in this case.

Comment: @otis_d - Without seeing your complete implementation, I don't see anything there that would be affected by iOS 15. I put together a quick sample using the code you posted, and it works as expected. To get more help, you may need to put together a [mre] that we can take a look at.